# 2 applications running on tomcat and cause out of memory. Is it because of low memory on VPS?

Tags: web-applications, vps

We are trying to run 2 applications on tomcat which is on VPS. The memory allocated is 512MB and burstable ram is 1256MB.
Now both both these applications have unique class names as folder names are different.
These are Java, JSF , Spring , hibernate applications.

Both of them are under respective folders packaged as two different wars.

Whenever we try to run them together, we get OutOfMemoryExceptions.

Are we doing something wrong or we need more RAM here ?

Answer (score 0):

There are two potential problems here 
1. Multiple web apps using the same connection pool jar. So there were two instances of class in same VM

I have described the problem and solution here
[Multiple webapps using same c3P0 connection pool](http://www.skill-guru.com/blog/2010/09/06/multiple-webapps-using-c3p0-connection-pool-on-same-server/)

2. We are using xml/xsl which is consuming too much memory. Need to look deeper into this.