# avoiding tomcat crash running two apps

Tags: java, hibernate, tomcat

I wrote a jsf/richfaces/hibernate web app and installed under tomcat.
Lately I quite rewrote (but not completely, many classes on the two apps have the same name) that app upgrading from richfaces 3 to 4.
My customer wanted both apps be usable at the same time and thus I deployed both under the same tomcat instance (7.40), considering that they have different urls and different context paths.
Testing that configuration, I quickly saw that it can't work ; as I login on both apps and run some trivial functions, tomcat crashes giving outOfMemoryError : PermGen space.
I tried to view memory usage on jconsole and it appeared not really critical, cause heap usage was around 150 mb on 256 mb available.
Any hint would be appreciated.
Flavio

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution at 
[2 applications running on tomcat and cause out of memory. Is it because of low memory on VPS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3581239/2-applications-running-on-tomcat-and-cause-out-of-memory-is-it-because-of-low-m)
Doing what explained in the that post, the first impression looks really fine.